# Custom tag attribute for iterator value

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I want a custom JSP tag that has an attribute which is a normal bean expression and names a list. The tag shall then render the list in a specific form.

I tried to write a custom tag with an attribute for s:iterator like this:

```
<%@ tag body-content="empty"%>
<%@ attribute name="list" required="true"  %>

<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<s:set var="varList" >${list}</s:set>
<s:iterator value="varList">(render item)</s:iterator>
```

In a different JSP I used it with a bean expression:

```
<my:listtag list="myObject.aList"/>
```

I expected it to iterate over "myObject.aList" but unfortunately this doesn't work. What seems to happen is, that the iterator tries to iterate over "myObject" instead of "myObject.aList".

What's going on and how can I get my desired bahaviour?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here we go. The Attribute must be defined of type "Collection" and the iterator variable must be given by "%{#attr.list}":

```
<%@ attribute name="list" required="true" type="java.util.Collection" %>

<s:iterator value="%{#attr.list}">(render item)</s:iterator>
```

In the other JSP I need to call it with the *value* of the variable, not the variable name:

```
<my:listtag list="${myObject.aList}"/>
```

yay!